# If $A+B+C= 180^{\circ}$ and $\cos A = \cos B \cos C$, then $\tan B \tan C$ is equal to?

Tags: trigonometry, examples-counterexamples

If $A+B+C= 180^{\circ}$  and $\cos A = \cos B \cos C$, then $\tan B \tan C$ is equal to?

(a) $1/2$

(b) $2$

(c) $1$

(d) $-1/2$

I can't figure out the solution, maybe I am missing an onward trick which I am unable to spot. I tried using the fact that $tan A = - tan(B+C)$, used the $tan(x+y)$ formula too, but unfortunately, it does not lead me anywhere. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A rather different, but no less interesting question is: how many triples (A, B, C) are there satisfying these relations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\cos (180-B-C) = \cos B \cos C\implies -\cos (B+C) =\cos B\cos C$$

Now we have $$-\cos B\cos C +\sin B \sin C = \cos B\cos C$$

Can you finish?

Comment: How did I miss that? :(

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (your attempt):
$$\begin{align}
\tan(B+C)&=\frac{\tan B+\tan C}{1-\tan B\tan C} \Rightarrow \\ 
1-\tan B\tan C&=\frac{\frac{\sin B}{\cos B}+\frac{\sin C}{\cos C}}{\tan(180^\circ-A)} =\\
&=\frac{\sin (B+C)}{\cos B\cos C\cdot (-\tan A)} = \\
&=\frac{\sin A}{\cos A\cdot (-\tan A)} = \\
&=-1 \Rightarrow \\
\tan B\tan C&=2.\end{align}$$

Comment: Aah, I was unable to see this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All possibilities are wrong!

Try $A=270^{\circ}$, $B=-90^{\circ}$ and $C=0^{\circ}.$