# Proving that a product of tangents is 2

Tags: proof-verification, trigonometry

This question came from my solution to this previously asked question

[If $A+B+C= 180^{\circ}$ and $\cos A = \cos B \cos C$, then $\tan B \tan C$ is equal to?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2843485/if-abc-180-circ-and-cos-a-cos-b-cos-c-then-tan-b-tan-c-is-eq?rq=1) (the answer is 2).

Although the solutions posted on that page are much simpler than mine, the answer I got sparked a new question I can't seem to solve.

My solution went as follows:

$$\tan(B)\tan(C)=\frac{\sin(B)\sin(C)}{\cos(B)\cos(C)}=\frac{\frac12(\cos(B-C)-\cos(B+C))}{\frac12(\cos(B-C)+\cos(B+C))}=\frac{\cos(B-C)-\cos(B+C)}{\cos(B-C)+\cos(B+C)}$$

$$\cos(B+C)=\cos(180^\circ-A)=-\cos(A)=-\cos(B)\cos(C)\\\cos(B-C)=\cos(B)\cos(C)+\sin(B)\sin(C)$$

$$\tan(B)\tan(C)=\frac{2\cos(B)\cos(C)+\sin(B)\sin(C)}{\sin(B)\sin(C)}=\frac{2}{\tan(B)\tan(C)}+1$$

$$(\tan(B)\tan(C))^2-\tan(B)\tan(C)-2=0$$

Let $u = \tan(B)\tan(C)$

$$u^2-u-2=0\qquad(u-2)(u+1)=0\qquad u=2, -1\implies\tan(B)\tan(C)=2, -1$$

From here, how do I deduce that $\tan(B)\tan(C)=-1$ is not a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You got
$$\cos\beta\cos\gamma=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(\beta+\gamma)+\cos(\beta-\gamma))=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(-\cos\beta\cos\gamma+\cos\beta\cos\gamma+\sin\beta\sin\gamma)=\frac{1}{2}\sin\beta\sin\gamma,$$
which gives $$\tan\beta\tan\gamma=2.$$
Id est, it can not be equal to $-1$, otherwise we obtain $\sin\beta\sin\gamma=\cos\beta\cos\gamma=0.$

Just in the given must be added $\cos\beta\cos\gamma\neq0$.